# How to minimize wear on brakes?

Tags: brakes, commuter, wear

My daily commute consists of a quite steep last part (around 1 km with average 12% steepness). On my way back home when going downhill, I have to extensively use my brakes to (more or less) keep the speed limit of 30 km/h, and to avoid risks of course. Is there an optimal "brake strategy" to reduce the wear on my brakes? For example, is it better to use them in "intervals" (going to 35-40 km/h and then braking back to 25), or use them constantly (keeping around 30 km/h)?

EDIT: Rim brakes

Comment: For long downhills, I tend to favor alternating front and back -- 15-30 seconds on one, and then the other.  With maybe a 10-second pause in-between.  This isn't for wear so much as safety -- if I were to sense the brakes losing effectiveness I would immediately bring the bike to a near halt, using both brakes, and then inch my way down.  But avoiding overheating one brake or rim by alternating should reduce wear as well.

Comment: brakes are consumables and a vital part of safe travel by bicycle, frequent service, and if necessary replacement, wont break the bank and should not be (harshly put) skimped out on.

Comment: I cycle the brakes - on reasonably hard for ~1-3 seconds then off until I need to brake again.   Whatever you do, don't hold the brakes half-on, its full on or full off.

Comment: @Criggie could you expand on that comment? I know you don't mean locking the wheel by "full on* but it could be read that way and modulating brakes is normal riding behaviour,so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @ChrisH Sure.  Fully On means a brake squeeze of a pressure that would stop you quickly and safely on a flat. Not a panic stop, but firmer than if you just want to wash off some speed.   A couple of seconds of full-on braking will slow you down quicker than 5-20 seconds of half-on brakes.  This lowers the overall temperature experienced by the rim and pads, keeping the whole brake system cooler and working better.  Hot brakes don't work so good, and weaknesses in tubes are stressed in heat and leads to flats.  Slow braking is bad braking on downhill.  Does not answer question, so commenting.

Comment: Thanks @Criggie. I understand now but don't completely agree (some reasons in my answer) One day I'll get round to modelling the rim temperature for the same hill height and bottom speed as a function of braking style - the difference in energy (i.e. the total heat load) is the same but cooling depends on a number of factors. Now wondering about an experiment too - maybe I should finally buy an IR thermometer.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I do exactly that, but dividing all the durations by ten.

Comment: @ChrisH - The amount of energy dissipated going down a hill (with a given final speed at the bottom) will be essentially constant, regardless of braking "style".  Wind "losses", of course, affect how much is left for the brakes, but for a given energy dissipation in the brakes, the heat generated will be constant.  The only significant variable (after wind) is that getting the rims really hot will increase the rate of heat loss.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, yes, I'd like to see whether - for the same total heat dissipation - a constant input or a pulsed input reaches a higher (e.g. pad) temperature, given the difference in airflow and instantaneous heat load. The difference will be small, and may come down to whether there's significant airflow between the pads and rims when not braking as the pad rubber is a poor thermal conductor. I could only model it (too?) crudely now as I no longer have access to thermal simulation software.

Comment: Relevant, interesting, (but not overly rigorous in the science or repetition.) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqMuxfHd9Vg   Rider uses a FLIR camera on different types of brakes, after descending the same grade.

Comment: It'd be interesting to have a battery and some electric brake, to try and recover some of the energy.  Downside is you'd have to carry the weight up the hill too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wear on rim brakes can be reduced by washing your bike to remove grit from the wheels, and by cleaning out the cleaning grooves in your brake pads.

You can also increase braking effect by sitting up as much as possible, so your body acts as an airbrake.  This will reduce the braking effort required by your rims.

Are there any routes with perhaps a greater distance but lower elevation changes?

Remember, no braking on the turns.  You need to drop your velocity before hitting the corner, then drift through the corner.  Braking on the turn makes you more likely to loose traction.

Comment: If one routinely takes this downhill it might be worth considering wearing a loose-fitting jacket, to increase wind drag.  Or, if you're really a fanatic about it, employ some sort of small parachute.

Comment: No breaking in turns is only when the surface is slippery, such as water or a thin layer of gravel. I didn't brake in corners on the hills here then I'd never brake! Even in such conditions you can brake, just be gentle.

Comment: ... and use the rear brake more.

Comment: A year or two ago I did some quick tests of upright vs. tucked (only on a hybrid so not very tucked). I used neither the pedals nor the brakes after passing a start line at a set speed (not set very accurately) On hills comparable to the OP's but a bit less steep the difference in peak speed was around 10% (quite consistently if I selected days with almost no wind).

Comment: @ChrisH there's a nice long steady grade sealed with smooth bitumen, around an hour's ride from home.  I was riding it on a MTB with knobbly tyres once, and got to an equilibrium of not pedalling, and I could hear the whirr/buzz of the tread on the road.  So I did the tuck thing by lowing the head, elbows in, cranks level, knees against frame.  Then I heard the pitch of whine increase and speed, to the point of "I need to brake now"  So no numbers, but aero on downhillis totally a thing.  Insane pros have been clocked at 100km/h+ on downhills.

Comment: @Criggie absolutely. 10% faster on my fairly minor test means around 20% more kinetic energy to dump if you have to hit the brakes at the bottom. This would only increase for bigger hills. I don't have a better test case on a regular ride as our roads are too crowded and often have junctions in the wrong places, with drivers who don't expect bikes to be going 50-60 km/h.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. The route I chose already is maybe slightly steeper than the alternative route, however, I believe that it is quite a bit safer, since it is a one-way road for a large portion, whereas the other route is extensively used by cars and quite narrow. Good point about sitting up!

Comment: Yep, sitting up makes a big difference.

Answer (score 3):

Front rims tend to stay cleaner than back rims, and dirt is abrasive so (as well as being good technique) a preference for the front brake will extend the life of your pads.

On downhills it's a bit different - heat is an issue not just for pad life but for safety. Hills round here tend towards short and sharp, so I use the back brake (lightly) for not going faster and keep the front for stopping. On longer descents I rest the back brake by giving the front a turn.

There are good reasons to avoid going fast-slow-fast-slow:

- following traffic (whether cars or bikes) won't expect sudden slowing on a clear road and you (presumably) don't have a brake light
- as your stopping distance increases a lot with speed you don't have to go much faster for hazards (like side streets because many drivers don't understand bikes that go quick) to get more significant.

Even good brake pads (which last longer than cheap ones) aren't expensive, and it's easy to change them yourself (front *or* rear in a session, then test, at least until you're experienced) so pad wear shouldn't be your top consideration - riding for the conditions should be.

Answer (score 3):

Another more expensive option is to add a third brake.  Tandems frequently have drum brakes in the hub of the rear wheel, and while they don't really stop the bike, they work to limit the top speed on a downhill.

Upsides

- continuous gentle braking to limit your top speed
- Rider can set the amount of braking effect - they're not on/off switches.

Downsides

- Cost of hub and have to replace all spokes with shorter ones due to the larger flange.
- You need a reaction arm, which means either a tab or a clamp on your chainstay on the left side.
- Have to rebuild your wheel to put them in instead of the existing rear hub
- Another brake control - my tandem used a bar-end lever for the rear drum.
- Its easy to forget to unset the brake, limiting your speed once off the grade.

I never had a problem with heat.

Hub from rear.  Note cassette is a 6 speed.
[image]

Hub with reaction arm onto chainstay
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't say whether you are using disc or rim brake.

With disc there are various grades of pad - sintered, organic and semi-metal (resin). Sintered last the longest.

Rim brake there are various different compounds available for the pads and it is a case of experimenting with the options. Swissstop offer high quality pads for various conditions.

Hard braking will also cause excessive wear - so the approach would be to be as smooth as possible on the brakes. This usually involves the technique of "feathering" the brakes - whereby the brakes are applied with *just* enough force to control speed.

Comment: I have rim brakes (edited the questions)